# Got always about 10% accuracy when training CIFAR-10 by VGG16 model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have always about 10% accuracy, when I training CIFAR-10 by VGG16 model.

I using standard VGG16 model, and sgd bellow:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0005, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

When I removed momentum, I have accuracy about 18%. What is wrong?

Here is confusion matrix:

```
[[   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [   0 1000    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

Best regards!

Comment: We cannot tell you what is wrong without more information, specially any source code you are using. Are you talking of training or testing accuracy?

Comment: That confusion matrix looks *very* suspicious...

Comment: Here is my full code:

https://github.com/simongeek/TFVGG16cifar10/blob/master/vggkeras.py

Comment: Is this truly for `epochs = 1`, as indicated in your code??

Comment: Always return 10%...For epochs = 1 or epochs = 10, 20, 50 etc.

Comment: Post your model here. There is something fishy the way you are passing things to your model

Comment: It's too long, check this link:

https://github.com/simongeek/TFVGG16cifar10/blob/master/vggkeras.py